# Action bar menu icons dissapear in onDrawerOpened

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm kind of new to Android. I added menu icons into my application.
Here is my code.

```
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:showAsAction="never" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_example"
        android:title="Logout"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        android:showAsAction="withText|ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/addLoc"
        android:title=""
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_location"
        android:onClick="gotoLocation"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/dealsPic"
        android:title=""
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_deals"
        android:onClick="doThis"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/profPicture"
        android:title=""
        android:orderInCategory="3"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_prof"
        android:onClick="userProfile"
        />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/namePerson"
        android:title="Nathalia Smith"
        android:orderInCategory="4"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:onClick="userProfile"/>
</menu>
```

After added theses menu icons in to my Action Bar menu icons appeared. but, when I Expand my Navigation drawer, icons just disappear and when I close it icons appear.

What I need is to appear these icons whenever the drawer is opened.

Here is my onCreate.

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        mTitle = getTitle(); //

        // Set up the drawer.
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
                R.id.navigation_drawer,
                (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));

        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#FFA500"))); // change the color of header

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,R.drawable.ic_menu, R.string.app_name,R.string.app_name)
        {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();          }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_deals);
    }
```

Here is my onDrawerClosed and onDrawerOpened

```
  mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,R.drawable.ic_menu, R.string.app_name,R.string.app_name)
        {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();          }
        };
```

hat I need is to appear these icons whenever the drawer is opened. Someone please help.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Look at the comments in the `onDrawerClosed()` and `onDrawerOpened()` methods.

Comment: try to remove invalidateOptionsMenu() method inside onDrawerClosed() and onDrawerOpened()  method

Comment: you saved my ass Mike M. Can you please post an answer. So, I can accept it. :) Because you are the one who told me first. :)

Comment: It's cool. No worries. You can just accept one of the posted answers, if you feel that one of them is an adequate answer. Thanks, though. Cheers!

Comment: Okay Thanks. I feel silly that I didn't even read the comments in the code. :):D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `invalidateOptionsMenu();` from below code as:

```
       mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,R.drawable.ic_menu, R.string.app_name,R.string.app_name)
                {
                    public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);

                    }
                    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {

                       getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);

                   }
                };
```

Also if you want always show the icons use `app:showAsAction="always"` like below:

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/dealsPic"
        android:title=""
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_deals"
        android:onClick="doThis"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

`invalidateOptionsMenu()` is used to say Android, that contents of menu have changed, and menu should be redrawn. For example, you click a button which adds another menu item at runtime, or hides menu items group. In this case you should call `invalidateOptionsMenu()`, so that the system could redraw it on UI. This method is a signal for OS to call `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`, where you implement necessary menu manipulations. Furthermore, `OnCreateOptionsMenu()` is called only once during activity (fragment) creation, thus runtime menu changes cannot be handled by this method.

Source of above information:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27984041/android-correct-use-of-invalidateoptionsmenu](http://Source)