# How to recreate options menu android fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-optionsmenu

At my fragment I have recyclerview with adapter. I would like to change menu items when I make long click on RV item. For this task I did:

1. Interface:

   ```
   interface Delete_Archive {
   fun delete_Archive_Data(note_id: Int, note_position: Int)
   }
   ```
2. Send data from click listener of adapter to fragment:

   ```
   holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener {
   deleteArchive.delete_Archive_Data(recordModel.id,position)
   true
   }
   ```
3. Receive data at fragment:

   ```
   override fun delete_Archive_Data(note_id: Int, note_position: Int) {
   }
   ```

I read that I have to `invalidateOptionsMenu()`, but after doing it I don't understand what I have to do. I wold like to add homeUp btn to toolbar and several buttons for some actions. For this I have to add and remove items dynamically or inflate another menu recourse. How I can do this?

Comment: I hope this will helps you [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27984041/android-correct-use-of-invalidateoptionsmenu)

Comment: @Sunny, thank you, it helped me, but how I can add homeUp btn to toolbar?

Comment: homeUp button means hamburger menu button right?

Comment: no,cross at the lest side

Comment: Can you Please add the image for reference.

Comment: I can switch this btn `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled` but I can't do it from onCreateOptionsMenu.