# invalidateOptionsMenu not triggering onPrepareOptionsMenu()

Tags: android, kotlin, menu, menuitem

From the main activity I'm simply trying to change the title of an item of a "basic menu" (drawer layout, navigatonView, menu.xml, setNavigationItemSelectedListener in the activity etc..) at runtime ( minSdkVersion 23,targetSdkVersion 29).

Basically there's a variable in shared preferences referring to the "logged user" and I would like to set that string as the title of the item or restore the default item title (stored in string.xml) if the user is "disconnected".

As suggested in others Q/A like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27984041/android-correct-use-of-invalidateoptionsmenu), for example, I'm trying to call invalidateOptionsMenu() 
which is supposed to trigger onPrepareOptionsMenu(), which I have overridden with my "logic".

NavigationView of the main activity

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout.....>
........
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/main_drawer_navigationView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:background="@drawable/background_gradient_orange"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
    app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"/>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The only method overridden for menu

```
override fun onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
    sharedPreferences.getString(CURRENT_EXT_USER,null)?.let {
        menu?.findItem(R.id.menu_item_change_user)?.title = it
    }?: kotlin.run {
        menu?.findItem(R.id.menu_item_change_user)?.title = getString(R.string.item_change_user)
    }
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu)
}
```

The problem seems that onPrepareOptionsMenu() it's never fired, not even when the activity is created or when invalidateOptionsMenu() is called.

I have tried also with: override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean { return true } but nothing happen. The only way I could make it work it's to do it "manually" with

```
main_drawer_navigationView.menu.findItem( R.id.menu_item_change_user).title = "user"
```

but I don't really like this solution

Comment: A `NavigationView` and its menu are completely unrelated to the options menu. They are totally separate things. That is, what you're trying to do is just not going to work. Your "manual" solution is exactly how to modify a `NavigationView`'s menu at runtime.

Comment: Damn, got it. I feel so dumb right now honestly. Thank you!